# adding install to QT pro file

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

when compiling qt **app** I'm running `qmake && make`.
I would like to run `make install` as well, so I've added the fillowing to my `pro` file:

```
target.files += $$OUT_PWD/$(DESTDIR)/$(TARGET)
target.path += /opt/zview
INSTALLS += target
```

but running  `make install`

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
```

How can I correctly add install to my pro file?

Comment: _when compiling qt_ are you speaking about compiling Qt, or a Qt app?

Comment: Maybe your files already there? Is there anything else in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qmake checks for file existence before adding it to install target. As your build target doesn't exist yet it fails.

You should omit "target.files" completely to let qmake decide itself (see "Installing Files" subsection under qmake's manual [Advanced Usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html)).

```
# target.files are set by qmake automatically as it's a well-known set name
#target.files += $$OUT_PWD/$(DESTDIR)/$(TARGET)
target.path += /opt/zview
INSTALLS += target
```